# Go JSON Marshal, is there a better way?

Tags: go, marshalling

I have a struct that is populated with `Unmarshal` from a web response. Then I want to take a particular nested field from this JSON structure and feed it into a different web request. The issue is that the field name gets removed when using `Marshal`. As a workaround, right now I'm doing the equivalent of:

```
type Message struct {
    Dogs json.RawMessage `json:"doggies"`
}

...

type Doggies struct {
    Dogs json.RawMessage `json:"doggies"`
}

var msg Message
// msg gets populated from a request

postBody, err := json.Marshal(Doggies{Dogs: msg.Doggies})
```

Which is messy. Is there a way that I can get Marshall to include the field name? So instead I could have

```
postBody, err := json.Marshal(msg.Doggies)
```

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you just use `json.Marshal(msg)`? Note that `msg.Doggies` evaluates to the **value** of the field. That value does not retain ANY "meta" information about the `msg` struct, including field information.

Comment: you should try `json.Marshal(msg)` as mentioned by @mkopriva. You can also check this playground https://go.dev/play/p/4UWBkXVt1al

Comment: That seemed to work fine. Thank you. I was overthinking this.